# Частичный доступ в гугл таблицах

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть документ googlesheets.
К нему имеют доступ несколько человек. Как сделать так, чтобы каждый пользователь мог вносить правки только в свою строку(строки).
Есть идеи как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 3):

Выделяете мышкой область - в вашем случае строку или столбец, кликаете в выделенной области правой кнопкой мыши - выбираете пункт <kbd>Protect range...</kbd> и указывайте доступ только тем кому можно.

Если хотите ограничить доступ к определенному листу - кликаете правой кнопкой → <kbd>Protect sheet...</kbd>